# How can $(\exists x\in Z)(\forall y\in Z)(x>y)$ and its negation, $(\forall x\in Z)(\exists y\in Z)(x\le y)$, both be true?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$$(\exists x\in Z)(\forall y\in Z)(x>y)$$

This statement is true since we can take any $y\in Z$, add $1$ to it which would yield $x\in Z$ always greater than $y$.

If we now negate this statement we get:
$$(\forall x\in Z)(\exists y\in Z)(x\le y)$$
This statement should be false, but if we take any $x\in Z$, add $1$ to it, we get $y\in Z$ such that $x\le y$ which makes the negation of a true statement a true statement??

---

Now there's probably something really wrong in my reasoning so can someone clarify this a little bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(\exists x\in Z)(\forall y\in Z)(x>y)$ is False, not True ...

There is an integer greater than all integers (including itself)?! No.

Indeed, when you say:

> $(\forall x\in Z)(\exists y\in Z)(x\le y)$
>
> This statement is true since we can take any $y\in Z$, add $1$ to it which would yield $x\in Z$ always greater than $y$.

what you really show is that:

$(\forall y\in Z)(\exists x\in Z)(x>y)$ is True (which indeed it is)

So, in case you had not yet realized this:  the order of the quantifiers matters!

Comment: Yes! I see the mistake now. I just started learning proof writing and I confused the order of quantifiers. That's a mistake I shouldn't have made. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer. I don't Know if it's Worth leaving the question online but maybe it helps someone.

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 You're welcome!  And yes, I think it might be helpful to someone ... your title is helpful in that regard as well.

Comment: True, I could've written a more informative title.

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 I think your title is just fine, actually!

Comment: Now that it's corrected, It's perfect!